# Creating Folders Based on a Column Macro Issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that creates new folders based on the data in Column Q. It works great except for the fact that Column R is required to be populated with data in order for it to work.

I don't understand this because the data in Column R is irrelevant. It doesn't give an error, the folders just don't show up for some reason.

```
Sub CreateFolders()


 Dim FolderListRange As Range
 Dim FolderRange As Variant
 Dim FolderName As String
 Dim ParentFolderPath As String
Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook


On Error GoTo Handle

ParentFolderPath = xWb.Path

Set FolderListRange = ActiveSheet.Range("Q2:Q64000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

For Each FolderRange In FolderListRange
    If FolderRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then GoTo Continue

    FolderName = ParentFolderPath & "\" & FolderRange.Value

    If FileSystem.Dir(FolderName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        FileSystem.MkDir FolderName
    End If

 Continue:
  Next

 Handle:
  End Sub
```

Comment: _It doesn't give an error, the folders just don't show up..._. Well, remove `On Error GoTo Handle` and you should see your error.

Comment: I just removed it, but it still doesn't come up with an error?

Comment: Column R is irrelevant? `FolderRange.Offset(0, 1).Value`...and FolderRange is a range in Column Q...offset by 1...*singing the alphabet song*...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Tim; I appreciate it. I'll go review my alphabet now. haha